# Prevent pwgen -y generating backticks or quotes? (or otherwise sanitize output)

Tags: bash, passwords

I'm using pwgen in a bash script. For security, we have to use the `-y` flag to include at least one special character. However, this frequently returns passwords with one or more of ` or " which break the surrounding script.

**Can I prevent these characters being generated?** If not, what's the cleanest way to remove, replace or otherwise sanitize pwgen's output to exclude these characters?

My current pwgen is;

```
intPW=$(pwgen -c -n -y -B -1 15)
```

which means intPW's value could be something like;

```
iqui`c:ee4so4Ch
hph7eew"ohr9Ee
```

I need to guarantee that every password has a symbol in it, just not one of the problematic symbols.

Anything I can think of in terms of replacement, from an if loop to a sed, breaks because I'm trying to target a backtick.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have `pwgen` version 2.08, you can use the new option `-r` to exclude unwanted characters

```
pwgen -cnyB1 -r \`\" 15
```

Comment: What a clean option. Thanks!

Comment: What if we also want to exclude backslash \ itself and on top of that make it an alias where the whole command is wrapped in quotes " ?

Comment: @kev To exclude the literal backslash character, you can try using the double backslash as the value for your option. So for example `pwgen -cnyB -r "\\"` should do the trick. Also, assuming that you want to make a bash alias for the whole command, usually I'll just wrap it inside single quotes such as `alias mypwgen='pwgen -cnyB1 -r "\\"'` otherwise the double quotes inside would not be interpret correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't also need to protect single quote characters, the following should be OK:

```
intPW=$(pwgen -c -n -y -B -1 15 | tr '`"' '$@')
```

That will translate ` to $ and " to @. Feel free to pick any other characters you fancy!

Comment: Entirely my error, but it appears I unluckily never saw a single quote pop up in my testing...even though they do. Just saw one such stinker now after about 40 pwgens :I Can this solution be adapted to also account for single quotes?

Comment: Yes, the same principle works. You just need the argument to tr to include a single quote too. I'll edit the answer when I'm not doing it from a mobile device so I don't muck it up!